# Set time zone for meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like add an event to my calendar with graph API.

I use this endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
I create my class event to registrer my event

```
    public class Event
    {
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public Body body { get; set; }
        public Start start { get; set; }
        public End end { get; set; }
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public List<Attendee> attendees { get; set; }
    }
```

I have issue to set correctly a starting date. My start object is like that

```
    public class Start
    {
        public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
        public string timeZone { get; set; }
    }
```

I try different method to set the value

```
lunch.start = new Start()
{
    dateTime = DateTime.Today,
    timeZone = "UTC" // Resource.DefaultTimeZone
};

lunch.start = new Start()
{
    dateTime = DateTime.Today,
    timeZone = "UTC+4" // Resource.DefaultTimeZone
};

lunch.start = new Start()
{
    dateTime = DateTime.Today,
    timeZone = "Pacific Standard Time" // Resource.DefaultTimeZone
};
```

But my meeting is still to the same time. How I could select the time zone to my meeting ?

Answer (score 0):

Set it to UTC.

```
lunch.start = new Start()
{
    dateTime = DateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString()
    // timeZone = "UTC" // This is supposed to be the friendly name like Pacific Standard Time. I think this is optional.
};
```